# Rethinkdb The many-to-many relationship

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I have tables of the following kind

entity

```
|id|title|
```

entity_authors

```
|id|authorName|
```

entity_to_authors

```
|id|entityId|authorId|
```

I managed to join the tables `entity` and `entity_to_authors`

```
r.table("entity")
    .get("f17234b6-b25c-4037-8dd1-314841967964")
    .merge({e -> r.hashMap("entity_to_authors", r.table("entity_to_authors").filter(r.hashMap("entityId", e.g("id"))).coerceTo("array"))})
    .run<Unit>(connection)
```

Now I need to get data from the table `entity_authors`
I did it this way (but it's wrong)

```
r.table("entity")
    .get("f17234b6-b25c-4037-8dd1-314841967964")
    .merge({e -> r.hashMap("entity_to_authors", r.table("entity_to_authors").filter(r.hashMap("entityId", e.g("id"))).coerceTo("array"))})
    .merge({e -> r.hashMap("entity_authors", r.table("entity_authors").filter(r.hashMap("id", e.g("entity_to_authors").nth(0).g("authorId"))).coerceTo("array"))})
    .run<Unit>(connection)
```

since here I use `nth(0)` to get the first line of data received from `entity_to_authors`
What should I do to get all the authors?

Sorry for my English!

Answer (score 0):

I was told that this is done so:

`.merge{ row -> r.hashMap("entity_authors", r.table("entity_authors")
    .filter { ea -> row.g("entity_to_authors").g("authorId").contains(ea.g("id")) }
    .coerceTo("array"))}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to write the query :-

```
r.table("entity")
  .merge(function(entity) {
    return {
     authorIds: r.table("entity_to_authors").filter({ entityId: entity("id")})("authorId").coerceTo("array")
    }
  })
  .merge(function(entity) {
    return {
     authors: r.table("entity_authors").getAll(r.args(entity("authorIds"))).coerceTo("array")
    }
  })
  .without("authorIds")
```

**Step 1 :**  Get the mapped `authorIds` array from first merge.

**Step 2 :**  Get the authors from authorIds from second merge. `getAll` normally takes comma separated values, to pass an array you need to use `r.args`.

**Step 3 :**  Lastly, remove `authorIds` property from result, we don't want the mapping in our result, we want mapped authors.

Hope it helps.